# Can't run rails db:create for postgres RDS on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I created an postgres RDS instance,** which I can connect to from my EC2 instance and my local shell**.
But for some reason when I run rails db:create I get the following error:

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_user"

Any pointers?

1. I can connect to the RDS instance from EC2 instance and local machine.
2. I expect rails to be able to run migrations as well, but it throws an error.

db.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: use
  password: gresgres

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['PG_RDS_DBNAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['PG_RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['PG_RDS_ENDPOINT'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['PG_RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: You should post some code. At least the `database.rb` config file

Comment: @Joe added db.yml content

Comment: Some questions: what is the result of Rails.env from rails console?Did you check that all env are loading right, so PG_RDS_USERNAME is equal to my_user?